# Как повернуть GridView с права налево?

Tags: java, android

Такая проблема... Мне необходимо для корректного отображения `item` в `GridView` мне нужно, чтоб `GridView` показывал их не слева направо, а справа налево... Я попробовал использовать в `XML GridView` `gridView.setRotationY(180)` все элементы зеркально отобразились и чтоб сами  `item`s правильно отображались я в адаптере сделал `item.setRotationY(180)`. И вот сама проблема в том, что теперь я на телефоне не могу нормально попасть пальцем на `item` ... Я нажимаю на один, а нажимается либо чуть ниже либо выше либо ваще не реагирует... Это только на моем телефоне так? Но было нормально...

**Вот код**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bhb"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".generals.Alfavit">

<!--android:rotationY="180" this line was add to rotate gridView-->

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:columnWidth="30dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="4"
    android:rotationY="180"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/check"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/checkb"
    android:onClick="checkYou" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Вот адаптер**

```
public class LettersAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context contextForLetters;

public LettersAdapter(Context context) {
    this.contextForLetters = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return Letters.getInstance().getLetterses().size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // makes adapter work faster and set letters in gridview
    ImageView imageView;

    if (convertView != null) {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    } else {
        imageView = new ImageView(contextForLetters);
        imageView.setRotationY(180);
         imageView.setBackgroundResource(Letters.getInstance().getLetterses().
                get(position).getIdIRForPechat());
    }
    return imageView;
}
}
```

Comment: А если все эти дела описать в XML? Для GridView и для item прописать `android:rotationY="180"` ?

Comment: Может, вам просто в адаптере данные надо отсортировать наоборот?..

Comment: @VAndrJ А как найти item в XML? GridView я сделал, но я не понимаю как добраться через XML к самому элементу

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko добавьте код как Вы объявляли `GridView`

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, Через `getItem(postition)` попробуй. Или нужно получить данные какие-то?

Comment: По-моему, с вашей задачей стоит посмотреть в сторону интернационализации, письма справа налево и аттрибута [`layoutDirection`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:layoutDirection)